# SharePoint ListData.svc "contains" string filter operator

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I'm using getJSON to retrieve list items from SharePoint like this:

> [site url]/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Keywords?filter=**startswith**(Title,'r')

I want to change it to retrieve this:

> [site url]/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Keywords?filter=**contains**(Title,'r')

which fails. Is there a "contains" operator for ListData.svc?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the good syntax is:

```
 [site url]/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Keywords?$filter=substringof('r',Title)
```

All operators are listed here :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc907912.aspx

Comment: It worked, thanks! Although the filter parameter is actually **before** the field name for whatever reason (unlike other filter operators):

`[site url]/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Keywords?$filter=substringof('r',Title)`

Answer (score 1):

Since ListData.svc follows OData protocol, you can try `substringof`. I never tried it myself but it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I used that in my query where I have to check & find `notesField` which contains the word `'Download'`, so for that I used following REST URL:

> _api/web/lists/getbytitle('SecureSystemData')/items?$select=SNotes&$filter=substringof('Download',SNotes)

The second parameter is Field name, i.e. internal column name.

Thanks.